# How to zip a pair of files with a specific naming convention?

Tags: zip

I have translation files in a folder similar to

```
domain-cs_CZ.mo
domain-cs_CZ.po
domain-da_DK.mo
domain-da_DK.po
domain-de_DE.mo
domain-de_DE.po
...
```

Now I would like to have all languages separated in a zip file called xx_XX.zip like

```
domain-cs_CZ.mo
domain-cs_CZ.po => cs_CZ.zip

domain-da_DK.mo
domain-da_DK.po => dk_DK.zip

domain-de_DE.mo
domain-de_DE.po => de_DE.zip
```

With a single command it's pretty simple:

```
zip xx_XX.zip *-xx_XX.*
```

but I'm searching for a way to get them all automatically.

Some things to consider:

- There are no other files in this folder
- some languages have the format `domain-xx`
- some languages have the format `domain-xx_XX`

Comment: What operating system? What scripting language? I've provided an answer using a Windows batch file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

`ls | sed 's/.*/& &/;s/domain-//;s/... /.zip /' | xargs -n2 zip`

Just be sure you don't have `.zip` files already in the directory, or add `--ignore .zip` after `ls` to remove them from directory list.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like all languages separated in a zip file called xx_XX.zip as follows

```
domain-cs_CZ.mo
domain-cs_CZ.po => cs_CZ.zip

domain-da_DK.mo
domain-da_DK.po => dk_DK.zip

domain-de_DE.mo
domain-de_DE.po => de_DE.zip
```

On Windows, use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem get a list of unique filenames
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`dir /b domain-*.*`) do (
  set _file=%%~nf
  echo !_filelist! | find "!_file!" > nul
  rem if true we have a new name, strip off domain- (1st 7 chars) and save to a file to process later
  if not !errorlevel! == 0 set "_filelist=!_filelist!!_file! " && echo !_file:~7!>>files.txt
  )
rem process the list
for /f %%f in (files.txt) do (
  zip %%f.zip *%%f.*
  )
rem tidy up
del files.txt
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>dir domain-*.*
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

15/02/2016  10:48                 0 domain-cs_CZ.mo
15/02/2016  10:49                 0 domain-cs_CZ.po
15/02/2016  10:49                 0 domain-da_DK.mo
15/02/2016  10:49                 0 domain-da_DK.po
15/02/2016  10:49                 0 domain-de_DE.mo
15/02/2016  10:49                 0 domain-de_DE.po
               6 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,774,192,197,632 bytes free

F:\test>test
zip cs_CZ.zip *cs_CZ.*
zip da_DK.zip *da_DK.*
zip de_DE.zip *de_DE.*
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).